# parse JSON Map in JQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following map where every key is a map which its values are lists as the following json:

```
{
  "key": {
    "source": ["element1", "element2"],
    "target": ["element1", "element2"]
  },
  "key2": {
    "source": ["element1"],
    "target": ["element1"]
  }
}​
```

I want to do the following:

1. Get key ( get("key2")) which will return the map
2. Go over every key in this map( source and target)
3. iterate over each item in the result list (element1, element2)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm confused about what you want to do .. do you have example output?

Comment: Convert the JSON (which is text) to a JS Object (e.g. `JSON.parse`, etc) - then deal with it *as a JavaScript object* (and not JSON). What's the issue(s) then? E.g. `obj["key2"]`, nested loops (or HoFs), nested nested loops (or HoFs) ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using jQuery's `.each()` to loop through the `key2` items.

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(yourJSONString);

$.each(obj["key2"], function(key, value){
    console.log(key); // <-- source, target
    $.each(value, function(arrKey, arrValue){
        console.log(arrValue); // <-- element1, element2 etc etc
    });
});
```

If you don't want to specify `key2` to target, and you want to go through all of the outer objects then:

```
$.each(obj, function(outerKey, outerValue){
    console.log(outerKey); // <-- key, key2
    $.each(outerValue, function(key, value){
        console.log(key); // <-- source, target
        $.each(value, function(arrKey, arrValue){
            console.log(arrValue); // <-- element1, element2 etc etc
        });
    });
});
```

You can also achieve the same without jQuery, by using the native `JSON.parse()` and  nested vanilla `for(var=0; i<something.length; i++)` loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
var o = {
  "key": {
    "source": ["element1", "element2"],
    "target": ["element1", "element2"]
  },
  "key2": {
    "source": ["element1"],
    "target": ["element1"]
  }
}​
var key = o.key2;
for(p in key)
{
 elementArray = key[p];
 for(var i=0;i<elementArray.length;i++)
 {
   //access element 1 and 2 here
 }
}
```

Comment: I think you accidentally capitalized the `I` here `for(var I=0` <--

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you needed, but it should lead you down the right path:

```
var things = {
  "key": {
    "source": ["element1", "element2"],
    "target": ["element1", "element2"]
  },
  "key2": {
    "source": ["element1"],
    "target": ["element1"]
  }
};

var get = function( key ) {
    var output = '';

    for( thisKey in things ) {
        if( thisKey === key ) {
            var myThing = things[ key ];

            for( thingKey in myThing ) {
                output += thingKey + ': ' + myThing[thingKey].join(', ') + '<br />';
            }

            return output;
        }
    }
}

document.write( get( 'key' ));
document.write('<hr />');
document.write( get( 'key2' ));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RucB3/